# Why boolean is not saved in preferences

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-preferences

I store many numerical values ​​and a few booleans in preferences. There are no problems with numbers, they are saved and read from memory exactly as I expect. But this is not always the case with logical values. For some reason, sometimes it happens that one value is saved (I checked that it is exactly that during debugging), and the next time a different value is read. However, this is not always the case. I don't understand why this is happening. I've searched for questions on preferences but haven't found any similar. Maybe I am doing something wrong.
Here is a piece of code:

```java
private Preferences preferences;
preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences(prefName);

private void savePref() {  
    preferences.put(getMap());
    preferences.put(getBool());

    preferences.flush();
}

public void loadPref() {

    if (preferences.contains(someValue) {
      for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> integerEntry : getMap().entrySet()){
           getMap().put(integerEntry.getKey(), preferences.getInteger(integerEntry.getKey()));
      }

      for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> integerEntry : getBool().entrySet(){
           getBool().put(integerEntry.getKey(), preferences.getBoolean(integerEntry.getKey()));
      }
     }     
}
```

UPD:
I still don't understand why, but everything works correctly on the emulator, but not on my phone. I guess I did everything right and the problem is not on my part.
I would still be happy to know why this situation can happen at all.

Comment: I think it's likely the error is in code you haven't shown.

Comment: @Tenfour04, Maybe, but I can't guess where. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I don't know anything except what you already posted.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, but maybe you would like to see some special places in the code, like closing the app. But honestly, I don't think it will help, because I just call these functions everywhere.

Comment: A good start would be to show us how you're verifying that the numbers are what you expect. In what context the above methods are called.

Comment: The numbers are in line with my expectations because they are exactly what they were before the application was closed. That is, the player collects a certain number of points, this value is saved, we close the game, open it again and see the same value of points. The load method is called once when the application is opened, saving occurs after each level and when exiting the game.